# Python, csv, merge rows in a column based on the same value

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

How can I merge rows based on a value in a column? Eg.

**Current Format:**

[image]

I'd like to have it as presented here:

**Expected Format:**

[image]

Those fields should be, of course, merged. Currently, I am writing everything row by row which is not what is being looked for.

Comment: i think you are looking for multi index feature in pandas. but after you did the multiindex, it will no longer be a proper csv file format;

Comment: A csv file has no way to represent merged cells. The best you could achieve would be blank fields in place of repeated values. You might consider sending your data directly to Excel and merging the cells there.

Comment: That looks more like excel than python.. you are trying to write to a csv? Like Yikang Luo mentioned, it is not possible in csvs (but in python's pandas module it is)

Comment: As commented before, you might want to work on an Excel file instead. Consider the [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html?highlight=merge%20cells) library that supports also merging cells.